# Twitter API response time

Tags: php, twitter

When I check Twitter API status, I see that average time for "/1.1/friends/ids" is now 676 ms.

[image]

But I get lower speeds than that. I made some checks. In my site's peak hours I get 1200-1300 miliseconds resonse time for "/1.1/friends/ids". I get 870-950 ms in low traffic hours.

```
tryout 1, main, time passed: 0.969 seconds
tryout 2, main, time passed: 0.871 seconds
tryout 3, main, time passed: 0.916 seconds
tryout 4, main, time passed: 0.846 seconds
tryout 5, main, time passed: 0.874 seconds

tryout 1, main, time passed: 1.215 seconds
tryout 2, main, time passed: 1.288 seconds
tryout 3, main, time passed: 1.175 seconds
tryout 4, main, time passed: 1.350 seconds
tryout 5, main, time passed: 1.249 seconds
```

Is it possible to lower the response time ? I don't know where to start to check?

I use [tmhOAuth](https://github.com/themattharris/tmhOAuth) for PHP.

Comment: That would probably be down to your server load, if it is dependent on your traffic levels. Upgrade your server, or transfer this to an offline process on a different server?

Comment: My server's load is low. Generally CPU is 10-15%. RAM usage is 60-65%. Load average is 0.3-0.4. I have throughput of 200-350 rpm.

Comment: Congested network interface? Try doing some requests of other websites to see if all HTTP requests are slowed to the same degree, or whether it is just Twitter.

Comment: I can say that response is slow with respect to Twitter API status. How can I say that other website connections are slow or fast ?